# What is the best to way develop an unmanaged C++ DLL for both Win32 and WinCE?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am interested in opinions on how best to setup a VS2008 project so that a DLL is compiled as both a smart device DLL as well as a C++ Win32 DLL. Is there an alternative to having two projects and the source files are shared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can do this by using more than one platform.  Tricky to get right though, you can't get the settings initialized from a project template.  Best thing to do is to start the project with a SmartDevice project template since it has the most custom settings.  Then Build + Configuration Manager, Active solution platform = New and select Type = Win32, Copy = None.

That last one is the painful bit, you'll have to change the Win32 specific settings yourself.  Best thing to do is to open a sample Win32 .vcproj in a text editor and check with setting overrides it has.  So you can reproduce them in your custom project.  Copy and paste works btw, that's the quickest and safest way.